# “Show hidden files and folders” option is not working

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have windows XP my both the radio buttons are unchecked 
[do not show hidden files and folders]
[show hidden files and folders] 
and I my checked value is already 1 and default value is 2 so its not working for me now please suggest a solution 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP operating system based systems, two types of files and folders exist - those that are displayed and those that remain hidden. The hidden files and folders can, however, be viewed in the Windows XP platform. A situation may arise when the user is unable to view the hidden files and folders. This happens if the system has been affected by a virus or there has been a change in the registry. To tackle this latter problem, one simply has to enter a required command in the command prompt and viewing is back to normal. 
Windows XP - Unable to display hidden files and folders

Due to changes in the registry or virus infection, you may no longer be able to access the options to display hidden files and folders (Tools > Folder Options). Here's a simple tip below that should help.

To find these options:

1. Click on Start menu, then click Run (or Windows key + R)
2. Type `cmd`, a command prompt window (DOS) will open
3. Type `regsvr32 /i browseui.dll` then press the Enter key and wait for a 
   confirmation window
4. Type `regsvr32 /i shell32.dll` then press the Enter key and wait for a 
   confirmation window
5. Close the command prompt

Open Windows Explorer, click on Tools > Folder Options

Please find the same in the link below:
https://ccm.net/faq/1549-windows-xp-unable-to-display-hidden-files-and-folders

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to un-check V in "Hide protected operating system files" below in the list. [Image here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/display-hidden-folders-in-xp/)
2. If you can't change view settings of the folder (both radio buttons unchecked) you probably don't have administrator privileges. To give them to your user (if you know administrator password) from [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001097.htm):

   - Open the Control Panel.
   - Double-click the User Accounts icon.
   - Click the user account you want to grant administrative rights.
   - Click "Change the account type"
   - Select Computer administrator and then the Change Account type button.